# react lifecycle method - correct way to filter

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. I have a product page component which is a page showing a particular product. What I am trying to do is that this ProductPage find the particular product in the products (which is an array of objects stored as props) and save it as the state before render it out.

I got these errors. I am not able to filter out single product from the array.

```
1) currentProduct is not defined.
2)Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Which lifecycle method should I use in order to resolve this? I am confused. Can someone explain to me?

In my ProductPage.js,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ProductPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            product: [],
            productId: this.props.match.params._id,
        }

      this.productsFiltering = this.productsFiltering.bind(this);
    }

    // update the state so that a product can be rendered
    componentDidUpdate() {
        const currentProduct = this.productsFiltering(this.state.productId);
        this.setState({
            product: currentProduct,
        })
    }
    
    // find a product based on the Id 
    // pass the _id from url to find out the single product
    productsFiltering = (productId) => {
        const productArray = this.props.products;
        return productArray.find(product => product._id === productId)
    }

    render() {
        // error
        const {name, price, description} = product; 
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{product.name}</span>
                <span>{product.price}</span>
                <span>{product.description}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    products: state.productsContainer,
});


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
)(ProductPage);
```

Comment: I think you've got a typo in `productsFiltering` - it looks like it should be `productArray.find(product => product._id === productId)`.

Comment: The root issue is that you're copying props to state, which there is no need to do. `ProductPage` displays a product and doesn't change, therefore no state is needed. Simply grab the matching product and store it in a variable then render. No `setState()` needed.

Comment: @MrCode Thanks for answering. It helps a lot. I follow what you just said and finally figure it out!

Comment: @sam1024 glad I helped solve it! I've added an answer so you can accept and complete the question (helps people see which questions still need answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue is that you're copying props to state, which there is no need to do.

ProductPage displays a product and doesn't change, therefore no state is needed. Simply grab the matching product and store it in a variable then render. No `setState()` needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove both errors if you change your code to this:

```
class ProductPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      product: []
    };

    this.productsFiltering = this.productsFiltering.bind(this);
  }

  // update the state so that a product can be rendered
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const productId = this.props.match.params._id;
    if (productId && this.state.product._id != productId) {
      const currentProduct = this.productsFiltering(productId);

      if (currentProduct) {
        this.setState({
          product: currentProduct
        });
      }
    }
  }

  // find a product based on the Id
  // pass the _id from url to find out the single product
  productsFiltering = (productId) => {
    const productArray = this.props.products;
    if(productArray.length){
      return productArray.find((product) => products._id === productId);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { name, price, description } = this.state.product || {};
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{product.name}</span>
        <span>{product.price}</span>
        <span>{product.description}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.productsContainer
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductPage);
```

-- always check for undefined or null properties

-- don't use setState in componentDidMount if the new state is constantly changing

-- avoid using a `state` which is directly drived from `props` because it's a bad practice and you can get `stale props`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the second error is still there.

Comment: @sam1024 I've added some more checks in `componentDidMount` which should fix the second error too, try again plz